# How to add an html element in JQuery UI Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I recently used the Jquery UI autocomplete and wondering how to add a header on top of the list.

Here's what I want to achieve with **Suggestions** as header:
[image]

Here's my script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.search').autocomplete({
source: 'search.php',
minLength: 1,
select: function(event,ui) {
var postid = ui.item.id;

if(postid != '') {
location.href = "post/" + postid;
}
}
});
});
```

I wish to add `<span>Suggestions</span>`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add this as a "category" by overriding how the autocomplete items are rendered (see: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories). Code is untested but might set you on the right path:

```
$('.search').autocomplete({
  source: 'search.php',
  minLength: 1,
  select: function(event,ui) {
    var postid = ui.item.id;

    if (postid != '') {
      location.href = "post/" + postid;
    }
  },

  _create: function() {
    this._super();
    this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
  },
  _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var self = this;

    // Add your unselectable "category"
    ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>SUGGESTIONS</li>" );

    // Add your other items
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
      self._renderItem( ul, item );
    });
  });
});
```